# Read/write cross-platform disk image

Tags: cross-platform, disk-image

I have a read-writable .sparseimage on a Mac; I'd like to start using the contents on a Linux machine as well. Is there a cross-platform read-write disk image container I can use? (The contained filesystem can be FAT32 or whatever.)

I'm familiar with Truecrypt, and can use that in a pinch, just wondering if there's anything "lighter weight" that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Did you end up finding what you were looking for? I'm looking for the same thing right now.